# How to use data from field array in meteor-tabular package

Tags: javascript, meteor, datatables

I'm using aldeed/meteor-tabular to display data from various collections in my app. However, I'm struggling with a particular case.
I couldn't find a way to display data from an array.
The case is that the selector returns a single document which basically looks like:

`{
    ... some data ...
    "jobs": [
        {
            col1: "Col 1 data",
            col2: "Col 2 data",
            ... some data ...
        },
        {
            col1: "Col 1 data",
            col2: "Col 2 data",
            ... some data ...
        }
    ],
}`

What I'm trying to achieve is to fill the table with data from the array in "jobs" field.

Is this currently possible?

Answer (score 1):

It seems currently it's not possible to have a table within a document this way...
https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-tabular/issues/102